# Google play services, sign in succeeded but error oncreateroom

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am trying google play services samples specifically ButtonClicker2000.
The sign in process is ok from the logcat also, but I have another error:

```
06-01 22:43:15.478: D/ButtonClicker2000(1565): Sign-in succeeded.
06-01 22:43:19.290: D/ButtonClicker2000(1565): onRoomCreated(6, null)
06-01 22:43:19.290: E/ButtonClicker2000(1565): *** Error: onRoomCreated, status 6
```

I don't know what it can be. Browsing the constants page error 6 is:
STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED.
This is a strange error because I am connected to the internet (also the successful sign in proves that)

I am using AndroVM as android device with google play services (and google play also) installed.
Any idea?

Comment: No one else experienced this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was driving me crazy for a while. You have to enable real-time multiplayer support in the Developer Console. It's one of the options in Linked Apps on the Game Services tab. See also [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#other_causes_of_setup_issues) troubleshooting page which links to [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_multiplayer_support)

Comment: Thank you so much. I nearly gave up :). that was the problem! The error code is misleading!!!