# Android: Leaderboard score submission error

Tags: google-play-services

I want to submit a score to my leaderboard. Sometimes it works but sometimes i get the error:

```
Error Code 6: STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED
```

I am connected to the internet and enabled multiplayer in the developer console. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
if(isSignedIn()){
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(mGoogleApiClient, this.leaderboardId,
                targetScore).setResultCallback(new LeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback(this));
}
```

LeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback:

```
@Override
public void onResult(Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult res) {
    Log.d("mylog","leaderboard upload result "+res.getStatus().getStatusCode()+": "+res.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
    if (res.getStatus().getStatusCode() == 0) {
        activity.showToast(activity.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.score_submitted));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),activity.getString(R.string.error)+": "+res.getStatus().getStatusMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes#STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED), **Error Code 6: STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED** means that a network error occurred while attempting to perform an operation that requires network access. You can retry it later. It might be setup issue so make sure that you have to enable real-time multiplayer support in the Developer Console. You can check on this [troubleshooting documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#other_causes_of_setup_issues). Here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877100/google-play-services-sign-in-succeeded-but-error-oncreateroom) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct. After I deleted the project in my developer console and set up a new one it is working.